# vuex actions and jsdoc: how to mark injected function parameter

Tags: vue.js, webstorm, vuex, jsdoc

Typical vuex action is:

```
const actions = {
  /**
   * @param {ActionContext} context passed by vuex
   * @param {Object} payload
   * @return {void}
   */
  myAction(vuexContext, payload) {...}
}
```

Where vuexContext would be injected for me, and in app I would use this function just as `myAction(payload)`. But for that case my WebStorm IDE complains about invalid number of arguments.

Maybe there is some workaround for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try marking `context` parameter optional:

```
/**
     * @param {ActionContext} [vuexContext]
     * @param {Object} payload
     * @return {void}
     */
    myAction(vuexContext, payload) {}
```

Please also vote for the related feature request: [WEB-29740](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-29740)

Comment: Thanks, I voted. About marking as optional, as for me it feels a little bit wrong to mark some param as optional if it followed by required params. And especially if it's not optional indeed. But I didn't find any better option though.

Comment: you are right. But I suggested a workaround that works. If you find a better one, feel free to provide your own perfect answer.

Comment: Just checked btw, this workaround doesn't work. Still have warnings about invalid number of arguments ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯